# Conflicting JARs: shouldn't WEB-INF/lib take precedence over all others places?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, classloader

My deployment environment is very messed up: jar files are scattered all over the system, and I have no control on it. For example my webapp uses a recent version of Javamail API, but is seems that in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` there are multiple copies of the same library (obviously all older and different versions). The same applies for database vendors' drivers, not to mention `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. **I can't clean up anything**, but obviously I need to ensure that my app gets the minimum required version of its dependencies, so I put all the required JARs in `WEB-INF/lib`. According to Servlet spec and [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html):

> When a request to load a class from the web application's WebappX
>   class loader is processed, this class loader will look in the local
>   repositories first, instead of delegating before looking

so it should solve my problem. But then the very same doc says:

> Therefore, from the perspective of a web application, class or
>   resource loading looks in the following repositories, in this order:
>
> 1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM
> 2. System class loader classes (described above)
> 3. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
> 4. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
> 5. Common class loader classes (described above)

And actually the classes in `/WEB-INF/lib` are loaded **after** system ones. Is this indeed expected behavior? Don't you find that the Tomcat docs is contradictory? Do you know any servlet container which guarantees that I can get the correct dependencies? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well, tomcat is a servlet container. It does not have control over the JVM. I would think the JVM would get priority first, then whatever application server your using. So this looks like expected behavior.

Comment: But don't you think this contrast with what Servlet spec says about the exception to the delegation model?

Comment: How did you eventually solve this problem?

Comment: I upgraded the libraries loaded by the extension class loader, made the team and the managers aware of the problem, and went on. If someone (or some tool) breaks the deployment, at least they know they should check this thing. There's the [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html), but it was infeasible to integrate in the buildchain - and I don't even know if it works with Javamail because of all the factories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the ext-folder is contaminated you are basically out of luck.

The only thing you can do, is to repackage all the code you need - including jars - in a separate package hierarchy and package with your application.  This would mean that `com.foo.Bar` would become `org.raffaele.com.foo.bar` or similar.  Then use only these new names.

Watch out for reflection and strings with class names, but it can be done.

I do not know if there is a tool that can fully automate this process.

Comment: Moreover, I wonder if this can be applied when you don't have the sources

Answer (score 4):

Bite the bullet and clean up.

Any solution you come up with that depends on classloading order is going to be fragile, confusing, and *very* hard to debug.  For example, if you forget to package a class in for some reason, suddenly you'll pick up a slightly different version...  I'll take a nice clean ClassNotFoundException over completely arbitrary behavior anyday!

Comment: Isn't the problem that he cannot?  (I agree that this is the _right_ solution, but he may not be allowed to do so)

Comment: Usually "cannot" means "I think it's harder and I don't want to".  Maybe he truly can't, but that doesn't stop it from being the right solution.  So I think it's still worth mentioning, even if only for other people that come here later.

Comment: I thought that usually "cannot" means "can not"... Oh well.

Comment: I simply cannot. The deployment machine is not under my exclusive control. I could even clean everything up, but what if later someone comes and puts anything new in? I agree this is *the wrong way* to manage things but hey... I thought JavaEE had a way to isolate webapps, but that `jre/lib/ext` breaks everything up

Comment: @Raffaele the ext-folder is not part of the webapps (but the underlying JVM) so you cannot blame JavaEE for this.